# Flutter video player fullscreen icon can't be pressed

Tags: iphone, flutter, dart, video-player, flutter-video-player

I am working on a flutter project to play video from file or network. I use chewie package to play videos. But while testing in iphone 13 emulator and some of the full screen mobile phone i cant press the full screen and mute button of video player.The controls are overflowed.
**And also while playing in full screen the video is not stretched. There are some black spaces in left and right side of the video.**
The image of both is attached and my video player code is as follows

```
callChewie(_videoPlayerController) async {
    bool startPlayer = false;
    // _videoPlayerController.initialize();
    _videoPlayerController.addListener(() {
      // print(_videoPlayerController.value.isInitialized);
      if (!startPlayer) {
        if (!_videoPlayerController.value.isPlaying) {
          startPlayer = true;
          _videoPlayerController.play();
        }
      }
    });
    chewieController = ChewieController(
        videoPlayerController: _videoPlayerController,
        aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
        autoPlay: true,
        looping: false,
        errorBuilder: (context, errorMessage) {
          print('error occured $errorMessage');
          Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 10), () {
            AwesomeDialog(
              context: context,
              dialogType: DialogType.ERROR,
              dialogBackgroundColor: Colors.white,
              borderSide: BorderSide(color: COLORS['PRIMARY_COLOR'], width: 2),
              width: 400,
              buttonsBorderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(2)),
              headerAnimationLoop: false,
              animType: AnimType.BOTTOMSLIDE,
              title: 'Something went  wrong.\nTry Again!',
              btnOkColor: COLORS['PRIMARY_COLOR'],
              showCloseIcon: true,
              btnOkOnPress: () {
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
            )..show();
          });
          return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(
            color: Colors.red,
          ));
        },
        showControls: true,
        allowFullScreen: !kIsWeb ? true : false,
        fullScreenByDefault: false,
        customControls: CupertinoControls(
          backgroundColor: Colors.black,
          iconColor: COLORS['PRIMARY_COLOR'],
        ));
    chewieController.addListener(() {
      if (chewieController.isFullScreen) {
        print('full screen enabled');
        SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
          DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight,
          DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,
        ]);
      } else {
        print('fullscreen disabled');
        SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
          DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
          DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
        ]);
      }
    });
  }

  playMovie(file) async {
    if (mounted) {
      setState(() {
        _videoPlayerController = null;
      });
    }
    _videoPlayerController = VideoPlayerController.file(file);
    await callChewie(_videoPlayerController);

    Navigator.of(context).push(
      PageRouteBuilder(
        opaque: true,
        settings: RouteSettings(),
        pageBuilder: (
          BuildContext context,
          Animation<double> animation,
          Animation<double> secondaryAnimation,
        ) {
          return WillPopScope(
            onWillPop: () {
              if (_videoPlayerController.value.isPlaying) {
                _videoPlayerController?.pause();
                _videoPlayerController?.dispose();
              }
              SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
                DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
                DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
              ]);
              return new Future.value(true);
            },
            child: Scaffold(
                backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
                body: Stack(children: [
                  MouseRegion(
                      onEnter: (event) {
                        setState(() {
                          isInfoVisible = true;
                        });
                      },
                      child: Dismissible(
                          key: const Key('key'),
                          direction: DismissDirection.horizontal,
                          onDismissed: (_) {
                            Navigator.of(context).pop();
                            _videoPlayerController?.dispose();
                            SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
                              DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
                              DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
                            ]);
                          },
                          child: OrientationBuilder(
                            builder: (context, orientation) {
                              isPortrait = orientation == Orientation.portrait;
                              return Center(
                                child: Stack(
                                  //This will help to expand video in Horizontal mode till last pixel of screen
                                  fit: isPortrait
                                      ? StackFit.loose
                                      : StackFit.expand,
                                  children: [
                                    SubTitleWrapper(
                                      videoPlayerController:
                                          _videoPlayerController,
                                      subtitleController: subtitleController,
                                      videoChild: Chewie(
                                        controller: chewieController,
                                      ),
                                    ),

                                    /*Chewie(
                                                controller: chewieController,
                                              ),*/
                                  ],
                                ),
                              );
                            },
                          ))),
                ])),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

and I call the playMovie() function on button press.

```
onPressed: () {
playMovie(file[index]);
},
```

[image: Screenshot of iOS Simulator of video player]

And also while playing in full screen the video is not stretched. There are some black spaces in left and right side of the video.
[image: Black spaces in both side of video in full screen]

Comment: try with wrapping `SafeArea`, I think it is status bar issue

Comment: can you say which widget should i wrap with safe area?

Comment: `Scaffold` or `body`, based on your need,

Comment: Thank you @YeasinSheikh ! that worked! but i am getting black spaces in both sides of the video. can you please help with that?

Comment: This is because of safe area, You can another thing, like preserving the space for this. check [this](https://medium.com/flutter-community/a-flutter-guide-to-visual-overlap-padding-viewpadding-and-viewinsets-a63e214be6e8)